# Given equation of parabola, find vertex and directrix

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Given that $x^2-bx+17-ay=0$ has vertex $(3,2)$, find the directrix and focus.

My attempt is to make it into the form $(x-h)^2=4a(y-k)$ which has focus $(h,k+a)$ and directrix $y=k-a$. Is this right?

$x^2-bx+17-ay=0$

$(x-\frac{b}{2})^2=4(\frac{a}{4})(y-(-\frac{b^2}{4a}+\frac{17}{a}))$ has vertex $(3,2)$ iff

$\frac{b}{2}=3$

$-\frac{b^2}{4a}+\frac{17}{a}=2$

Solving this gets me a=4 and b=6 so the focus is $(h,k+a)$=$(3,2+4)$=$(3,6)$,

and the directrix is $y=k-a=2-4=-2$